# Ransom Note-Leetcode

Tags: java, algorithm, for-loop, data-structures

I am trying the [383. Ransom Note](https://leetcode.com/problems/ransom-note/) LeetCode challenge:

> Given two strings `ransomNote` and `magazine`, return true if `ransomNote` can be constructed from `magazine` and false otherwise.
>
> Each letter in `magazine` can only be used once in `ransomNote`.
>
> #### Example 1:
>
> ```
> Input: ransomNote = "a", magazine = "b"
> Output: false
> ```
>
> #### Example 2:
>
> ```
> Input: ransomNote = "aa", magazine = "ab"
> Output: false
> ```
>
> #### Example 3:
>
> ```
> Input: ransomNote = "aa", magazine = "aab"
> Output: true
> ```

Here is my solution to the above LeetCode problem:

```
class Solution {

    public boolean canConstruct(String ransomNote, String magazine) {

        if (ransomNote==null || ransomNote.length() == 0) return true;
        if (magazine==null || magazine.length() == 0) return false;
        boolean flag=false;
        boolean visited[]=new boolean[magazine.length()];
        Arrays.fill(visited,Boolean.FALSE);
        for(int i=0;i<ransomNote.length();i++){
            flag=false;
            for(int j=0;j<magazine.length();j++){
                if(ransomNote.charAt(i)==magazine.charAt(j) && !visited[j] ){
                    visited[j]=true;
                    flag=true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return flag;
    }
}
```

I'm able to pass 110 cases out of 126 but there is some minor error in the code. I'm unable to find the error even in my dry run.

Test case that is not passing:

```
Input:
"fihjjjjei"
"hjibagacbhadfaefdjaeaebgi"

Output: true
Expected: false
```

Comment: I'm surprised that your code passes as many cases as you say. The code is essentially only checking the last letter of the ransom note. That's because you set `flag` to `false` for every letter, and then set it `true` if a non-visited match is found. So the final `flag` value only depends on the outcome of the last letter.

Comment: So what should I do???

Comment: Think again about your logic?

Comment: You can patch the code you already have, or start from scratch with a whole new design. I recommend the latter. Hint: `counting sets` for the magazine and the ransom note.

Answer (score 3):

The outer `for` loop should be exited if at the end of the inner loop, `flag` is still `false`, because that means you didn't find a match for that character.

It is of no use to continue with matching other characters when that happens, and worse, continuing can make `flag` `true` again in the last iteration of the outer loop, which would give a wrong result.

So add as the last line of the outer loop body:

```
if (!flag) return false;
```

Note that this algorithm is not efficient on very large strings, as it has a time complexity of O() where  and  are the lengths of the two strings. It can be done in O(+) if you use a map with frequency counts for each letter in the second string.

Answer (score 1):

```java
public static boolean canConstruct(String ransomNote, String magazine) {
    int[] arr = new int[26];

    for (int i = 0; i < magazine.length(); i++)
        arr[magazine.charAt(i) - 'a']++;

    for (int i = 0; i < ransomNote.length(); i++) {
        int offs = ransomNote.charAt(i) - 'a';

        if (arr[offs] > 0)
            arr[offs]--;
        else
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

O(m+n) solution with O(max(m,n)) space complexity

```cpp
class Solution {
public:
    bool canConstruct(string ransomNote, string magazine) {
        unordered_map<char, int> m1;
        unordered_map<char, int> m2;
        unordered_set<char> s;
        for(char& c : ransomNote) {
            m1[c]++;
            s.insert(c);
        }
        for(char& c : magazine) {
            m2[c]++;
        }
        for(char c : s) {
            if (m2.find(c) == m2.end() || m2.find(c)->second < m1.find(c)->second) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Python

```
class Solution:
    def canConstruct(self, ransomNote: str, magazine: str) -> bool:
        result = False
        for i in ransomNote:
            valueRansomNote = ransomNote.count(i)
            valueMagazine = magazine.count(i)
            if 1<=valueRansomNote <= valueMagazine:
                result = True
            else:
                result = False
                break
        return result
```

Answer (score 0):

**Java Solution**

```
class Solution {
    public boolean canConstruct(String ransomNote, String magazine) {
        
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(magazine); 
        StringBuilder rn = new StringBuilder(ransomNote);
     
        for(int i =0; i < ransomNote.length();i++) 
        { 
            if(str.indexOf(ransomNote.substring(i,i+1))!=-1)
            {
                 str.deleteCharAt(str.indexOf(ransomNote.substring(i,i+1))); 
                 rn.deleteCharAt(rn.indexOf(ransomNote.substring(i,i+1)));   
            }
              
        }
        
        return rn.length()==0;
        
    }
}
```